# Add files to ZIP without paths, using SharpZipLib

Tags: c#, zip, sharpziplib

I need to combine 3 files into 1 zip file and make it available to download for the user. I am able to achieve my requirement except one thing: it zips the files into the subfolders.

For example, my files are located like the following:

```
C:\TTCG\WebSites\Health\ABC.CSV
C:\TTCG\WebSites\Health\XYZ.CSV
C:\TTCG\WebSites\Health\123.CSV
```

But in the zip file, it zip the files in the folder by using "TTCG\WebSites\Health\" as the path.  Please see the attach file.

[image: Example]

I don't want the folders in the path. I just want 3 files in the zip file without folders. How can I achieve that?

My codes to generate the zip file is as below:

```
ZipFile z = ZipFile.Create(Server.MapPath("~" + @"\Accident.zip"));

//initialize the file so that it can accept updates
z.BeginUpdate();

//add the file to the zip file        
z.Add(Server.MapPath("~" + @"\ABC.csv"));
z.Add(Server.MapPath("~" + @"\XYZ.csv"));
z.Add(Server.MapPath("~" + @"\123.csv"));        

//commit the update once we are done
z.CommitUpdate();
//close the file
z.Close();
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Based on the FAQ, you have to strip the folder path out manually:

> **How can I create a Zip file without folders?**
>
> Remove the path portion of the filename used to create a ZipEntry
>   before it is added to a ZipOutputStream
>
> `ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(Path.GetFileName(fullPath));`

The FAQ can be found [here](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/SharpZipLib_FAQ.ashx).

It seems to be a limitation of the library.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

If you have your files in a FileSystemInfo, you can use:   `z.Add(file.FullName, Path.GetFileName(file.FullName));`

This will add your files in the root directory of your zip.

Comment: @MatthewLock that method takes 2 strings like that for me. SharpZipLib v0.86.0.518

Answer (score 2):

```
z.Add(pathToFile, pathInZipFile);
```

Comment: This doesn't compile the Add method doesn't take 2 strings like that