# Make multi download Asp.net zipFile class

Tags: c#, asp.net

to make multi download of files I need to use ZipFile class. Im using .Net 2010 and I need  a reference to ZipFile class which is avialable in .Net 2012 can i get a link for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is with [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893891/creating-zip-file-using-sharpziplib) and [these samples](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/wiki/Zip-Samples) might help you get started.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/), IMO it's much easier to use than SharpZipLib, here are the examples of usage:

http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples&referringTitle=Home